# The relation of the measure of the boundary and the measure of the set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck with proving the following statement: Suppose that the set $A$ has measure $0$. I should prove that the boundary of A need not be of measure $0$.

This is how far I could go. If the set A has measure zero, then there is a countable rectangle covering of it, $Q_1,Q_2,...$ such that the sum of the volumes of those coverings are smaller than an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$. And then there is a covering of the set $R^n-A$. if, I think, I can show now that the the coverings of the boundary is smaller than $\varepsilon>0$, then I would be done. But I dont know how to carry out this last step, I am a little new to these concepts. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try the rationals

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any countable dense subset $A$ of $R^n$, i.e. the closure of $A$ is $R^n$. (E.g. on the real line take $A=$ the rational numbers.) Then the boundary of $A$ also equals $R^n$, so the boundary has positive (even infinite) measure. But since $A$ is countable, it has measure $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Some confusions, could you please elaborate them?: do we generally conclude that if the set $A$ is countable, then it has measure $0$?

Comment: Yes, any countable set has measure 0

Comment: @primenumber57: By countable additivity, if points have measure zero, every countable set has measure zero. Of course, it might be that points have positive measure (but isn't in case of Lebesgue measure).

Comment: Yes, say $A=\{a_n:n\ge1\}$, cover $a_n$ with a rectangle with area $\varepsilon/2^n$, then the total area of these rectangles is at most $\sum_n \varepsilon/2^n = \varepsilon$, then take $\varepsilon\to 0$, the conclusion is that $A$ has measure $0$.